# Oxyplot: How to give every point on my lineseries a color

Tags: c#, pdf, plot, oxyplot

I am using oxyplot. I need a `LineSeries` combined with a HeatMap.
I allready found the `ScatterSeries` that kind of does what I need:

[image: Scatter]

But I don't want single circles - i want a line.
Something like this would be perfect:

[image: My own heatmap]

Can I achieve this with oxyplot and how?